# [Spread Sheets API v4][JAVA] How to get Row from value?

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    sheetsService = getSheetsService();
    String range = "Sheet1!A1:A10";

    ValueRange response = sheetsService.spreadsheets().values()
            .get(SPREADSHEET_ID, range)
            .execute();

    List<List<Object>> cell = response.getValues();

    if (cell == null || cell.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No data found.");
    } else {
        for (List row : cell) {
            if (row.contains("SUNFLOWER")) 
            {
      
                System.out.println("Value exists");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to do something like `row.contains("SUNFLOWER").get(THE ROW THAT THIS VALUE EXISTS IN)`

I'm a bit stuck on this part and *very* likely not reading the API thoroughly.

In short --> I found value which I know exists on Column A now from that value I wanna get the row number.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf` to get the cell index.

Just bear in mind that it will start counting from `0`, so you have to do a `-1` to the value.

```java
for (List row : cell) {
    if (row.contains("SUNFLOWER")) 
    {
        System.out.println("Value exists");
        System.out.println(cell.indexOf(row));
    }
}
```

Comment: Was this answer helpful for you? Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers